# Can't Scaffold Identity in my ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

[image: error]

**There was an error running the selected code generator:
'Package restore failed. Rolling back package change for Swarojgaar'**

This error occurred while trying to scaffold identity in my asp.net mvc project, the .net version is 6.0

I had scaffolded Identity in my MVC project previously while learning, but since my project progressed, I realized I had to make some changes to it. So I removed the Areas folder where Identity was stored. And I tried re-scaffolding this all once again but with some changes in my ApplicationDbContext. It shows me this error now. I am stuck here and can't progress any further. Please help me!

I tried downgrading all of my Nuget packages as well as upgrading them. But none of this worked for me.

Comment: To get any hope of help, you need to post the error message!

Comment: You can have a try to create a new project  to  scaffold Identity.